am using pytorch forecasting and fitting a temporal fusion transformer for multi stock. how model works?
how to analyze the model? My target is close price, my config is this:
training = TimeSeriesDataSet(
combined_data,
time_idx="time_idx",
target="Close",
group_ids=["Ticker"],
max_encoder_length=60,
max_prediction_length=1,
static_categoricals=["Ticker"],
time_varying_known_reals=["Dividends", "Stock Splits"],
time_varying_unknown_reals=["Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"],
allow_missing_timesteps=True
)
Prepare data loaders
batch_size = 128
train_dataloader = training.to_dataloader(train=True, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0)
validation = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(training,combined_data,predict=True,stop_randomization=True)
val_dataloader = validation.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=batch_size*10, num_workers=0)
Initialize the TFT model
tft = TemporalFusionTransformer.from_dataset(
training,
learning_rate=0.03,
hidden_size=16,
attention_head_size=1,
dropout=0.1,
hidden_continuous_size=8,
output_size=7,
loss=QuantileLoss(),
log_interval=10,
reduce_on_plateau_patience=4
)
Can some one guide on how to evaluate the model for each ticker?
Tried:
best_model_path = trainer.checkpoint_callback.best_model_path
best_tft = TemporalFusionTransformer.load_from_checkpoint(best_model_path)
Expecting to compare actuals vs precited with RMSE or MAE?
Also, is this correct?
from pytorch_forecasting.metrics import RMSE
predictions = best_tft.predict(val_dataloader, return_y=True, trainer_kwargs=dict(accelerator="cpu"))
RMSE()(predictions.output, predictions.y)
from pytorch_forecasting.metrics import MAE
predictions = best_tft.predict(val_dataloader, return_y=True, trainer_kwargs=dict(accelerator="cpu"))
MAE()(predictions.output, predictions.y)
